# JTable Printing dialog with Locale

Tags: java, swing, printing, dialog, jtable

im working with Java Swing. 
Im trying with print method of Jtable...

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ignore) {
    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Page {0,number,integer}");
    try {
        table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null);
    } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
        System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To show a printing dialog . Its work fine ..

[The printing dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwAZZ.png)

But i want to change the text dialog language to Spanish with a Locale class , how can i do it ???

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `table.setLocale(locale)`?

Comment: Yes, with table.setLocale(new Locale("es","ES"));
But the printing dialog dont change .

Comment: How about `JComponent.setDefaultLocale()`? This applies to the entire application.

Comment: I put JComponent.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es","ES")); on my constructor. 

I have this:

The Locale of my Jtable changed but the printing dialog is still showing at US Locale .

System.out.println(table.getLocale().getDisplayLanguage());
table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null);

Comment: Here is an interesting page from back in the day: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1287832

Comment: Here is another one that tells how to completely replace the `PrinterJob` class. This is the class that has the code to show the print dialog. The one bit of source I could find used the system print dialog box. I wonder why your example doesn't show that.

Comment: please post the link for replace PrinterJob class

Comment: Oops. http://www.applettalk.com/custom-print-dialog-vt14358.html this mentions how to replace it.

Comment: i solve it with your link : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1287832.

Comment: Just adding reflection to change the ResourceBlunde before Jtable.print() method...

try
    {
        Class cl = Class.forName("sun.print.ServiceDialog");
        if (cl != null)
        {
            Field fld = cl.getDeclaredField("messageRB");
            if (fld != null)
            {
                fld.setAccessible(true);
                fld.set(cl, ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.print.resources.serviceui_es"));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex11)
    {
        ex11.printStackTrace();
    }

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Diego

I copied your solution here so it can be more easily read.

It was inspire by the old forum entry here: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1287832

---- Begin ----

Just adding reflection to change the ResourceBlunde before Jtable.print() method...

```
try { 
    Class cl = Class.forName("sun.print.ServiceDialog"); 
    if (cl != null) { 
        Field fld = cl.getDeclaredField("messageRB"); 
        if (fld != null) { 
            fld.setAccessible(true); 
            fld.set(cl, ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.print.resources.serviceui_es")); 
        } 
    } 
} catch (Exception ex11) { 
    ex11.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

---- End ----

I may want to search and find it someday.

Comment: Great!, i cant autoanswer my own question because i dont have enough reputation to do it.

Comment: Took care of that for you. Do you have any other suggestions of how to make it clear that you figured it out, not me?

Comment: I saw the ServiceDialog.class of the rt.jar with Java Decompiler. There is a property like : private static final String strBundle = "sun.print.resources.serviceui";  perhaps i could change the string value to sun.print.resources.serviceui_es and then compile .

Comment: It might be better to just change the call above to `ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.print.resources.serviceui", new Locale("es", "ES"))` and use the other form of the bundle getter.

Comment: Looking at the source of that class, how does it set the locale for the bundle? Perhaps, if it calls `getBundle()` as you did, without a locale, all you have to do is change the default locale for the whole application.