# Java printing dialog with Czech locale

Tags: java, printing, locale

I have problem setting locale in printing dialog in java, specifically setting Czech locale. I found solution for setting locale [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840588/jtable-printing-dialog-with-locale) and it works but it works for new Locale("es", "ES") but not for new Locale("cs", "CZ"). Can someone help me, please? I tried to set default locale too: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("cs", "CZ"));` but with same result, only ES worked :(.

Comment: maybe this site will help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html

Comment: Try `Locale.forLanguageTag("cs_CZ")`

Comment: I have already set locale for: `private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", new Locale("cs", "CZ"));` and it works fine. "cz" instead of "cs" is not correct :) and it does not work. I am going to try your suggestions, thx.

Comment: @Stefoan you can't simply make up language codes.

Comment: Can you try `new Locale("cze", "CZ")` ?

Comment: @ccheneson [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html) you can find supported locales (czech is on row 27). JamesB can answer your comment too :) like Stefoan's, whos comment accidentally dissapeared a while ago :). But thanks for try.

Comment: @LuciusAgarthy. Because what I did is to look at the Locale API which says for the 2 argument constructor : 'language - An ISO 639 alpha-2, country - An ISO 3166 alpha-2'. So if you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639, you will see that for ISO 639 alpha-2, there is a code `cze/ces`for czech

Comment: @ccheneson anyway, this change did not help, thank you. I tried your suggestion with German locale. "de", "DE" worked but "ger","DE" did not work.

Comment: @LuciusAgarthy : I supposed  you are expecting the printing dialog in swing to be in czech. If yes, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html - search for '
User Interface Translation' Czech is not in the list

Comment: @ccheneson Hey man, you are great and I am blind. Thank you a lot. Can you write it as answer I will chech it solved. Another think is how can I do my translation? I am java newbie and do not know where to start, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Locale description](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html), section "User Interface Translation"

> The user interface elements provided by the Java SE Runtime
>   Environment 6, include Swing dialogs, messages written by the runtime
>   environment to the standard output and standard error streams, as well
>   as messages produced by the tools provided with the JRE. These user
>   interface elements are localized into the following languages:

[image]

So it looks like the UI elements are only translated in few languages

Unfortunatemly, I dont know how to add localization files in order for you to have your UIs in czech. Maybe some swing specialist can help you

Maybe this can help you getting started

Comment: Thank you for your time and help and sorry for my previous rude comment. I will try to google it out or I will post another question.